# JQuery conflict, use two version

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project, I have to use two different version of JQuery.

The JQuery UI require JQuery1.11.2
The Fancybox require JQuery1.9.0 (not latest version)

Ho can I do to resolve the conflict to these JQuery.

```html
        <!--Main JQuery-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <!--OR
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script
        -->
        <!--Bootstrap-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!--Main JQuery UI-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <!--JQuery UI plugins-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.rcarousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.tooltip.js"></script>
        <!--Fancybox-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
```

Comment: [You can](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1566595/492258)

Comment: It's a kind of different question. He's asking how to set up jQuery UI with another jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.noConflict(true)` .

> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.

**For more read [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)**